# Serving static file from Compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I'm trying to have a self-executable app that will runs jetty and a Compojure webapp. The user who will deploy the app should be able to modify manually the css files and some configurations files, so packaging as a WAR is not a solution for me.

My idea is to have a self-executable JAR in one directory and a webdata/static/css directory under it.

However when using the following route, the file in the css directory are not served:

```
(route/files "/static" {:root (str (System/getProperty "user.dir") "/webdata")})
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Does it work from REPL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the error, the path wasn't specified correctly. This code works:

```
(route/files "/" {:root (str (System/getProperty "user.dir") "/webdata/public")})
```

The tree structure of the project is then like this:

```
standalone-jar.jar
webdata
    |_public
      |_css
```